# Compare voxel models for shape similarities?

Tags: arrays, matrix, comparison, voxel

I have a collection of voxel models represented as both multidimensional arrays and obj polygon meshes. I need to compare these models against a reference model for similarity/differences.

ie: If the reference model and test model each contain a voxel sphere that is the same in size and shape, but the test model's sphere is shifted by a several voxels in the x axis, a direct comparison of the arrays will indicate these models are significantly different. I am looking for a comparison that might indicate that the test model is more similar to the reference model than one that contains an abstract shape.

Comment: Most efficient thing I can think for lookup performance (post-processing) would be to add some sort of metadata to each model when it is created that outlines in rough details what shapes it contains and there rough sizes. Otherwise, you'll have to go through each array/polygon mesh and analyze it piece by piece. Not really sure what your constraints are here though is this a one time thing? Does it need to be done multiple times during a runtime?

Comment: The analysis is being done on models that have been created and saved previously to determine similarity to the reference model, so a slow analysis is acceptable.